# Given a field K with characteristic $p$ ($p$ prime) show that $K$ contains exactly one subfield with $p$ elements

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

can anybody give me a hint on how to prove this statement?
I am given a field $K$ with char($K$) = $p$ and $p$ prime. I need to show that $K$ contains exactly one subfield with $p$ elements. I understand that in order to prove this I need to prove that such a subfield exists and in a separate step prove that only one can exist. I also know that the cardinality of $K$ must be $p^n$ for some $n \geq 1$. I tried proving the existence via induction over $n$ but got nowhere. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Take the multiplicative unit $\;1\;$ and prove that $\;\overbrace{1+1+\ldots+1}^{p \;\text{times}}=0\;$ ... and this $\;p\;$ is minimal. The rest is for you.

Comment: The cardinality of $K$ doesn't have to be $p^n$. It can be infinite.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that $K$ has a subfield of order $p$, observe that the map $f: \mathbb{Z} \to K$ defined by
$$f(m) = m\cdot 1,$$
is a homomorphism and the kernel is $p\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, the image of $f$ is a subfield of $K$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Thus $K$ has subfield $F$ of order $p$.

Note that $F$ has 1. It also has $p$ elements. Now, $k\cdot 1$, $1\leq k \leq p$, are all distinct elements and hence are the elements of $F$. As any subfield of $K$ contains 1, it must also contain $F$ and hence, there is only one subfield of order $p$.

Comment: This is correct. But it would have been better to post it as just the hint the OP asked for, as in the comment from @DanAntonio .

Comment: How the kernel of $f$ can be $\Bbb Z_p$? The kernel is a subset of the domain (in this case $\Bbb Z$).

Comment: In the sense $p\mathbb{Z}$ - a typo.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker - Agreed.

Comment: I didn't understand why there was a down vote! Anything wrong in this other than that it could have bee transferred to comment section and a typing error?